# count record have 2 value in one record elasticsearch

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, filter

I have an elasticsearch index containing documents like this:
This is presented for sucessful scanning:
`------WebKitFormBoundaryAqmzT9FybTB2TeKq Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob" Content-Type: image/png  PNG  IHDR ------WebKitFormBoundaryAqmzT9FybTB2TeKq--`
This is presented for unsucessful scanning:
`------WebKitFormBoundaryB6KphyzaUAjHoCED Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blob" Content-Type: image/png  PNG  IHDR`

I want to count how many records i have that they contain 2 value "------WebKitFormBoundaryXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX". "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" is changed in each record

I tried to use 2 filter but it can't work

Comment: Hello, are you working on `dev tool` or some `api client` ?